# Setting name of file in FileService api in gae/j

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

i wrote a servlet which is uploading blobs successfully but it is uploading with no name how to set the name of uploaded file in the servlet

here is  segment of servlet code

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {



         FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

          // Create a new Blob file with mime-type "text/plain"

          String url="http://www.cbwe.gov.in/htmleditor1/pdf/sample.pdf";
          URL url1=new URL(url);
          HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
          String content_type=conn.getContentType();
          InputStream stream =conn.getInputStream();
          AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("application/pdf");

          file=new AppEngineFile(file.getFullPath());
         Boolean lock = true;
          FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);

          // This time we write to the channel directly
          String s1="";
          String s2="";

          byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);


          writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
          writeChannel.closeFinally();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass filename as a second parameter to [`fileService.createNewBlobFile("application/pdf", "filename.pdf")`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService#createNewBlobFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can get file name from your URL

String fileNameWithoutExtn = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('.'));

Then pass fileName as a parameter

```
FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock,fileNameWithoutExtn );
```

Comment: `openWriteChannel(..)` does not take three parameters.